# Сделать фоновую картинку адаптивной к любому размеру контейнера

Tags: css

```css
.one{
    background-image: url("https://www.kolesa.ru/uploads/2016/05/kruiz-evro-6-980x0-c-default.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.one p{
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <p>100 years</p>
</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать адаптивным фоновое изображение к разным размерам контейнера, чтобы фоновая картинка с изменением размера контейнера всегда была под его размер и не обрезалась при уменьшении размера контейнера

Comment: а сейчас что не устраивает?

Comment: картинка режется справа

Comment: Ну, `backogrund-size: 100% 100%;` решит эту проблему, но пропорции картинки изменятся ... `cover` - самый оптимальный вариант для адаптивности, иначе у вас будут "уши", так как тут либо сохранение пропорций и обрезание, либо потеря пропорций и картинка четко вписанная в контур ... других вариантов нет чисто физически.

Comment: спасибо, тоже вариант